# SQLiteCommand.Transaction Required?

Tags: c#, sqlite, transactions, system.data.sqlite

I'm using [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/), and I have some code where I'm wrapping a series of commands in a SQLite transaction.

Is it required to set the `Transaction` property to the transaction instance? It seems as though the command automatically picks it up from the connection.

The reason this is important to me is determining what I have to pass down to helper functions--i.e. just a reference to the connection or to the transaction as well.

**Edit:**

Here's a simplified example.

```cs
private void ExecuteSql(SQLiteConnection conn, IEnumerable<string> sqlStatements)
{
    using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var sql in sqlStatements) ExecuteSql(conn, sql);
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw; // pass up to higher level
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
private void ExecuteSql(SQLiteConnection conn, string sqlStatement)
{
    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn)
    {
        //Transaction = trans,      -- necessary?
        CommandText = sqlStatement,
    })
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Transaction Object has some Method Overloads.. can you show some code in regards to what you are trying.. you can also name the Transaction when creating new SqlTransaction("somename") look at either of the links below [Sql Transaction](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30181&seqNum=3) || [MSDN SqlTransaction Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've added a simple example. Note that this is SQLite so we're talking about an `SQLiteTransaction`.

Comment: [SQLLiteTransaction](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.html) look at this one

Comment: Transaction = trans, I am not sure if this will work. Anything within the first using statement will be basically disposed so there will not be a trans object for you to refer it to the Transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to set the `Transaction` property manually.

Everything you do with the connection while the transaction is open will be tied to that transaction. However, this might not hold true for other database engines (although in general I think it does), so be careful if ever you change your DB.

I find the ADO.NET interfaces convoluted for no good reason; there's lots of redundancy, and providers often have to jump through hoops to get optimal performance with certain parts of the interface (e.g. the `IDataParameter`/`IDataParameterCollection` monstrosity).